# Having trouble validating the type

Tags: java, instanceof

The goal is to make a custom `ArrayList`. So far it's worked, however, once I try checking to ensure only the initialised type is entered into the array, I start running into problems (arrayType cannot be resolved to a type -- I am using eclipse).

My code so far:

```
public class MyArrayList implements MyList
{
    private Object[] theList; // array of objects
    private Class<?> arrayType;
    /**
     * Constructor - start with an empty array
     */
    public MyArrayList()
    {
       theList = new Object[0];
       arrayType = Object.class.getClass();
    }


    /**
     * Constructor - start with an empty array
     */
    public MyArrayList(Object type)
    {
        arrayType = type.getClass();
        theList = new Object[0]; 
    }


    /**
     * Adds a new element at the end of the list.
     * @param the object to add. Validation is done to ensure correct type.
     * @return true if element successfully added, false if parameter is null
     */
    public boolean add(Object toAdd){


        //THIS IS NOT WORKING

        if (!(toAdd instanceof arrayType.getClass())){
            return false;
        }




       if ((toAdd != null)) {
           int newSize = size() + 1;
           Object[] tempList = new Object[newSize];
           for (int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
               tempList[i] = theList[i];
           }
           tempList[newSize-1] = toAdd;
           theList = tempList;
           return true;

       }else {
        return false;
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is kind of crazy.  If you just want to store an `Object`, then everything is an object, you don't need to check that.  This seems like homework, better check with your instructor.  If you're supposed to be type checking the array then you need to do something very different (well, at least somewhat different).

Comment: You may just use **generics** instead of manually checking each element, that's what they where designed for.

Comment: There actually is a reason to use type checking like this, but it should be used with generics.  And anyone who knows generics should be able to write code like this, easily.  So my conclusion is it's a homework assignment in a first year class and the student has wandered into the deep end.  Best to ask the instructor before going further.

Comment: You can't use `instanceof` operator with a dynamic type. You have to use the reflection method [`Class.isInstance(Object)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-).

Comment: Note that a custom `ArrayList` that only increases by `1` after each `add` is super inefficient as reallocation (expensive) needs to be done for each `add` call then. Same holds for `remove` methods. An usual approach is to **double** or **halve** the capacity (depending on the operation) (there's actually *deep* math behind, you may research for detailed explanations and values).

Comment: *FYI:* `Object.class.getClass()` is not what you think it is. `Object.class` is already the class of objects, so calling `getClass` on a `Class` object will give you the class of classes, not the class of objects.

Comment: @Andreas, that is what I thought. My prof had mentioned we would need to use the instanceof operation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with an expression like this

```
toAdd instanceof arrayType
```

is that the right-hand argument of `instanceof` has to be a class **literal**, such as

```
toAdd instanceof Person
```

If the type you're checking against isn't fixed at compile type, you usually want the [`isInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isInstance-java.lang.Object-) method to test a value's dynamic type.

```
arrayType.isInstance(toAdd)
```